# Why does zh-Hans CultureInfo object return Zh-CN as Name?

Tags: .net, culture

As per the Title.

Why does .net behave like below?

```
var c = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("zh-Hans");

c.IetfLanguageTag == "zh-CN"; //true Why is it like that?
c.Name == "zh-CN"; //true Why is it like that?
```

I understand that there are fallbacklanguages but is there a way to find out that I actually used "zh-Hans" as the input for the object? I need that string to find for a database query and the data is stored as "zh-Hans"

Comment: If you use the constructor instead of `CreateSpecificCulture` it works as expected. No idea why.

Comment: So to answer your question, no, if you use `CreateSpecificCulture` that information is lost because a different culture is returned. [Here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/cultureinfo.cs,44db57d9e190258e,references) is the source. The last line changes the culture because `IsNeutralCulture` is `true` for `zh-Hans` and `zh-CN` is it's specific culture.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnste/archive/2007/12/13/zh-hans-zh-hant-and-the-old-zh-chs-zh-cht.aspx